# How to deal with answers that answer something different completely

Tags: discussion, answers

So, let's assume there is an answer which answers something else completely than what was originally asked. (For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177364/983912) 'answer')

How should this be treated? Flag for not an answer? In the case above, I'd even argue it's no more than a comment, but this question is more general. Assume there is an amazingly detailed and correct answer, which just answers something else completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Down-vote, comment. move on.

1. If the answer is just wrong, if you flag as "not an answer" it's likely to get declined with the following reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

2. If the poster has less than 50 rep then that might explain why they posted an answer instead of a comment, but we (the moderators) are not here to allow people to circumvent the rules by converting it to a comment for them. In cases like we may well just delete the non-answer.

Comment: Makes sense, cheers!